# angular equivalent to object prototype

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Now i wish to create an object that you can instanciate at any time but that can still use angular services:

Take for instance the following object:

```
var myObject = function (variableOne, variableTwo) {
    this.variableOne = variableOne;
    this.variableTwo = variableTwo
};

myObject.prototype.useAngularService = function () {
    return $sessionStorage.user;   
};
```

Ofcourse this `object` cannot use `$sessionStorage` but my question is how would you create an object like that, that actually could utilize angular services?

The reason why i want to use this method instead of a service or a factory is basicly that i want different instances of this object and i am not looking for a singleton solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could return your type from a `factory`. The factory would then have the Angular services and you would close around them.

```
yourModule.factory('yourName', function($sessionStorage) {
    var myObject = function (variableOne, variableTwo) {
        this.variableOne = variableOne;
        this.variableTwo = variableTwo
    };

    myObject.prototype.useAngularService = function () {
        return $sessionStorage.user;   
    };

    return myObject;
});
```

You can also request any registered service with `$injector.get(...)` but that makes for brittle code.

Answer (score 1):

You would inject `$sessionStorage` as a dependency into your object upon construction:

```
var myObject = function ($sessionStorage, variableOne, variableTwo) {
    this.$sessionStorage = $sessionStorage;
    this.variableOne = variableOne;
    this.variableTwo = variableTwo
};

myObject.prototype.useAngularService = function () {
    return this.$sessionStorage.user;   
};
```

You would then create a service which acts as a factory for such objects:

```
function myObjectFactory($sessionStorage) {
    this.$sessionStorage = $sessionStorage;
}

myObjectFactory.prototype.getInstance = function (variableOne, variableTwo) {
    return new myObject(this.$sessionStorage, variableOne, variableTwo);
};

myModule.service('myObjectFactory', myObjectFactory);
```

You then include that factory as a dependency for your controller or other service:

```
myModule.controller('myController', function (myObjectFactory) {
    var obj = myObjectFactory.getInstance(1, 2);
    obj.useAngularService();
}
```